# Expand Dataframe containing JSON object into larger dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas with two columns.  One is an ID and the other is a long JSON object, which is the same object for each object in the dataframe.  My goal here is to create columns for each key in the JSON object.

Here is an example of the input

```
ID  request_json
175431467   {"Rate":"50","Groups":"7 months - 3 years"
```

I'd like to expand this into a dataframe with three columns: ID, Rate, and Groups.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with `join` or `concat`:

```
import json

df = df[['ID']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['request_json'].apply(json.loads).values.tolist()))
print (df)
          ID              Groups Rate
0  175431467  7 months - 3 years   50
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df['ID'],
                pd.DataFrame(df['request_json'].apply(json.loads).values.tolist())], axis=1)
print (df)
          ID              Groups Rate
0  175431467  7 months - 3 years   50
```

Comment: Neither of these are working.  For both, it just renames the request_json column to 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [38]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.to_dict('r'))
Out[38]:
          ID request_json.Groups request_json.Rate
0  175431467  7 months - 3 years                50
```

Comment: This doesn't change my dataframe

Comment: @mangodreamz, you would need to assign it back or to another variable